# The Tab key isn't being detected in Java on Mac

Tags: java

I'm trying to make an application which uses the tab key to do something. I've implemented the KeyListener interface and I'm able to program all the other keys. But when I press the Tab key and in the keyPressed() method I put this:

System.out.println(ke.getKeyCode());

I get no output. The 'Tab' key is the only which gives no output. All the other keys have their relative keycode printed. Why is this?

Comment: The Tab key is handled by the [Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html). Also, why are you using a KeyListener? Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). I suggest you read the tutorial to determine if key bindings should be used for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)` on the control that you listen on (JTextField?).

EDIT:
The Tab key is usually used to switch input focus between UI controls, for easier keyboard input without the need for a mouse. When a UI control receives a key press event it first tries to "consume" it on its own, and if the key is a special key (Tab, Shift-Tab, etc.) then the control consumes the event and doesn't propagate it further. On the other hand, if the key is not a "special" key it propagates the event to attached listeners (if any). Calling `setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false)` disables this built-in behavior for the control (but in this case just for FocusTraversal, i.e. Tab and Shift+Tab), so that event gets propagated to listeners.

Comment: Wow thanks it worked. I'm just wondering, what does this method do? (Besides letting the application detect the tab key).

Comment: @raghavkansal: Ok, updated the answer with an explanation. Btw, you should accept the answer if it's correct.